# Following method call prevents JLabel from getting visible

Tags: java, swing, action, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I have a short question. I tried to google it, but it seems, that I can't find the correct keywords for good results. So here is my problem:

I have a JButton. Its actionPerformed is doing this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                lblConverting.setVisible(true);
                input.writeToCSV(chosenPath);
                lblConverting.setVisible(false);
                lblSuccess.setVisible(true);    
            }
```

Due to the long execution of my `writeToCSV`-method, I want to show a message, which my `lblConverting` contains. So during the execution of `writeToCSV`the user should see a message, which tells him to wait some minutes. Instead it looks like, that `lblConverting`gets visible "too late", so that it is set invisible shortly after `writeToCSV`is finished, right before it gets invisible again.

So, is there a way to get that label visible, before the method executes? Should I use something like SwingWorker? The first line of the `actionPerformed` is the only place in my code, where I want to do this. So a really short solution is preferred.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: `lblConverting.setVisible(false);`  BTW - if `lblConverting` implies a `JLabel`, note that the easiest & most reliable way to make a label invisible is `lblConverting.setText("");` ..

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I saw that post, which you linked, before, but it seemed kinda long to me. But your link to the Oracle doc really helped! I just needed a few lines to achieve my goal. 
I didn't know, that the better way is to use the `setText()` instead of the `setVisible()`. I would always suggest, that it would be the better way to use the `setVisible()`-methods instead. Interesting. I will keep that in mind.